# Prove that 7-sorted and 11-sorted array would be sorted by InsertionSort in O(n)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a porblem with simple prove:
Prove that if array is 7-sorted and 11-sorted  time of InsertionSort would be O(n).

`k sorted: for every i A[i] <= A[i+k]`

I assume, the fact that both 7 and 11 are prime numbers is important. 
Also `num of swaps = num of inversions`, so if i would prove that: for every element `num of inv < some const num`, time complexity would be `O(some const num * n)` so `O(n)`.

But i do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The little trick here is that any number above m=60 can be written as `n*7 + k*11`. (You can prove this by constructing the numbers `[m;m+6]` as a*7+b*11, (a,b)>0 and and if we can build n as a linear combination we can also build n+7, thus we can build [m;+infinity] ).

Assuming that your array is sorted in ascending order, `for any {x, N>m}, A[x] < A[x+N]`.

Thus, the lowest value of your array is in the interval `[0;m]`, the second in `[1;36]` and so on.

And finally, to sort your array you need `m*n = O(n)` combinations!